# What is the translation of moon overhead and moon underfoot in hunting context ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

For hunting purposes, some hunters follow the moon phases to hunt accordingly. There a two important moments:

- When the moon is directly overhead in the sky (**moon overhead**)
- When the moon is directly underfoot in the opposite side of the earth's sky (**moon underfoot**)

I would like to know the translation in french of **moon overhead** and **moon underfoot** in the context of hunting. If that can help, here's an article (in french) about the moon phases in hunting: https://leplacoteux.com/2019/10/leffet-de-la-lune-sur-le-deplacement-des-chevreuils/

Comment: The article you link to just uses *pleine lune* (full moon) and *nouvelle lune* (new moon).

Comment: I linked the article as reference to explain how hunters use the moon to hunt. It's only to give some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Directly overhead” is said “au zénith” and the opposite is “au nadir”.

But, in our latitudes, the moon is never “Directly overhead”, it happens only between the “tropics”.

Comment: Ok I understand. So, for moon overhead, I could say "lune au zénith" and moon underfoot would be "lune au nadir" ?

Comment: @AmineZ.: AFAIK, yes it would.

Comment: Beware that while *au zénith* is generally a well understood expression (although mainly used to name various indoor arenas in France), *nadir* is a rare word and likely puzzling for the vast majority of native French.